# Reference Counting in C99

Tags: c, memory-management

(I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mneri/refc); there are few improvements as suggested by other users in the comments)

As we know, C99 has no garbage collector. To address the problem of manually deallocate objects I wrote a little framework for reference counting. I would like to have comments about the style and clarity of the code and about the idea itself.

The main idea is to supersede `malloc ()` function with a new function named `alloc ()`. This function allocate the bytes needed for an object plus some meta information. The client of the library should follow this pattern:

- Allocate objects with `alloc ()` function instead of  `malloc ()`
- Whenever an object is assigned to a variable (e.g. `v = object`) the client should make a call `retain(object)`
- Whenever a reference to an object is lost the client should call `release(object)`

The following figure shows what happens in memory after a call to `alloc ()`:

```
+---+---+---------+
| 1 | 2 |    3    |
+---+---+---------+
  ^       ^
  p       q
```

Memory area noted with (1) is an integer, counting references to the object. Memory area noted with (2) is a pointer to the destructor function (`typedef void (*Destructor) (void *object);`); whenever the reference count reaches 0 this function is called. (1) and (2) form what the code calls `ObjectRecord`. Memory area noted with (3) represents the space needed by the actual object. The figure also shows two pointers, namely `p` and `q`. `p` is the pointer to the `ObjectRecord` and `q` is the pointer to the object. `alloc ()` function returns `q` (the pointer to the actual object) so the client is not bothered by metadata.

The code uses two macros (`OBJECT_TO_RECORD` and `RECORD_TO_OBJECT`) to "translate" from `p` to `q`. `mem.h` library contains function `malloc_or_die ()` that simply terminate the process upon failure.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mem.h"
#include "object.h"

#define OBJECT_TO_RECORD(ptr) ((ObjectRecord *) (((char *) ptr) - sizeof (ObjectRecord)))
#define RECORD_TO_OBJECT(meta) ((void *) (((char *) meta) + sizeof (ObjectRecord)))

typedef struct {
  unsigned int count;
  Destructor destroy;
} ObjectRecord;

void *
alloc (size_t size, Destructor destroy)
{
  ObjectRecord *record = (ObjectRecord *) malloc_or_die (sizeof (ObjectRecord) + size);
  record->count = 0;
  record->destroy = destroy;
  return RECORD_TO_OBJECT (record);
}

unsigned int
refsof (void *ptr)
{
  ObjectRecord *record = OBJECT_TO_RECORD (ptr);
  return record->count;
}

void
release (void *ptr)
{
  ObjectRecord *record;

  record = OBJECT_TO_RECORD (ptr);
  assert (record->count > 0);
  record->count--;

  if (record->count == 0)
    {
      if (record->destroy != NULL)
        {
          record->destroy (ptr);
        }

      free (record);
    }
}

void
retain (void *ptr)
{
  ObjectRecord *record = OBJECT_TO_RECORD (ptr);
  record->count++;
}
```

---

Now, let me give you some examples. Imagine we are building a [Java-like `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Our data type looks like:

```
typedef struct {
  void **elems;    /* Resizable array for the elements. */
  size_t size;     /* Number of elements actually in the array. */
  size_t capacity; /* Size of the array. */
} AList;
```

To create a new array list we use the function

```
AList *
alist_new ()
{
  AList *alist = (AList *) alloc (sizeof (AList), (Destructor) alist_destroy);
  alist->elems = malloc_or_die (ALIST_DEFAULT_CAPACITY * sizeof (void *));
  alist->size = 0;
  alist->capacity = ALIST_DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
  return alist;
}

static void
alist_destroy (void *alist)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < alist->size; i++)
    {
      release (alist->elems[i]);
    }

  free (alist->elems);
}
```

Since the array list is created with `alloc ()` function, when the reference counter goes to 0, `alist_destroy ()` is called automatically. `alist_destroy ()` calls `release ()` on each element it was holding. If the counter of one of these elements goes to 0, its destructor gets called automatically. Obviously, when we add an element to the `ArrayList` we should increment its counter.

```
void
alist_append_element (AList *alist, void *elem)
{
  /* Before appending the element to the array list, we ensure it can contain them. If not we let the array grow. */
  if (alist->capacity == alist->size)
    {
      alist_grow (alist);
    }

  retain (elem);
  alist->elems[alist->size++] = elem;
}
```

Now we can use our array list.

```
AList *alist = alist_new ();
retain (alist);

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    /* The dummy element is retained by the array list. */
    alist_append_element (alist, dummy_new ());
  }

/* We release alist. Every element it contains will be released, too (see alist_destroy()) */
release (alist);
```

The example above is very simple and probably doesn't justify all the complexity introduced by the library. A slightly more complex example is shown below.

```
/* We have two array lists: alist_1 and alist_2. alist_1 is filled with some objects. */

/* We put the elements of alist_1 that satisfy the predicate into alist_2. */
for (i = 0; i < alist_size (alist_1); i++)
  {
    if (predicate (alist_get_element_at (alist_1, i)))
      {
        alist_append_element (alist_2, alist_get_element_at (alist_1, i));
      }
   }

/* Now we release alist_1. All the elements of alist_1 will be released, too. The
elements that we put in alist_2 have the reference counter set to 2; a call to
release () decrements the counter without freeing them. */
release (alist_1);
```

---

You probably noticed that in function `alist_new ()` I used "standard" `malloc_or_die ()` to instantiate `elems` array. I wrote this example by hand right now and I've been very lazy. In the real world I would probably create functions to allocate that array, like:

```
void **
array_new (int nmemb)
{
    return (void **) alloc (sizeof (void *) * nmemb, (Destructor) array_destroy);
}
```

And for primitive arrays:

```
int *
array_int_new (int nmemb)
{
    return (int *) alloc (sizeof (int) * nmemb, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48271/discussion-on-question-by-mneri-reference-counting-in-c99).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way to write those macros would be

```
#define OBJECT_TO_RECORD(object) ((ObjectRecord*)(object) - 1)
#define RECORD_TO_OBJECT(record) ((void*)(record + 1))
```

This does the arithmetic directly in units of `ObjectRecord`, so you don't need the `sizeof` operator.

Functions are better than macros, and there's no reason that the object<->record conversions *need* to be macros. We should trust the compiler to inline these:

```
static ObjectRecord *toRecord(void *object) { return (ObjectRecord*)(object) - 1; }
static void *fromRecord(ObjectRecord *record) { return record + 1; }
```

---

In C, [We don't normally cast the result of `malloc()`](//stackoverflow.com/a/605858), so you should write:

```
  ObjectRecord *record = malloc_or_die (sizeof (ObjectRecord) + size);
```

or:

```
  ObjectRecord *record = malloc(size + sizeof *record);
```

(I don't like `malloc_or_die()` - guessing from the name, it sounds user-hostile. Terminating the entire application is definitely overkill for a fairly normal failure case, and not something that a library would want to be doing. And this is the kind of code that is otherwise useful for libraries, I think.)

There are other approaches (such as registering a failure handler), but I think it's best to copy the existing `malloc()` interface, and return a null pointer on failure.  Every competent C programmer knows how to handle that.

---

### My version

This has some additional changes, some of which are subjective preferences.  As a C++ programmer, I obviously prefer prefix increment/decrement operators.  I also find early exit preferable to conditionals, and don't like explicit comparisons against NULL.  Your opinions may differ!

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Internals */

typedef void (*Destructor)(void*);

typedef struct {
    unsigned int count;
    Destructor destroy;
} ObjectRecord;


static ObjectRecord *objectToRecord(void *p)
{
    return (ObjectRecord*)p - 1;
}
static void *recordToObject(ObjectRecord *r)
{
    return r + 1;
}

/* Public implementation */

void *alloc(size_t size, Destructor destroy)
{
    ObjectRecord *record = malloc(size + sizeof *record);
    if (!record)
        return record;

    record->count = 0;
    record->destroy = destroy;
    return recordToObject(record);
}

unsigned int refsof(void *p)
{
    return objectToRecord(p)->count;
}

void release(void *p)
{
    ObjectRecord *record = objectToRecord(p);
    assert(record->count > 0);

    if (--record->count)
        /* still referenced */
        return;

    if (record->destroy)
        record->destroy(p);
    free(record);
}

void retain(void *p)
{
    ++objectToRecord(p)->count;
}
```

(Compiled without warnings with my usual compiler: `gcc -std=c11 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses`).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments and this valuable reply. One thing that bother me is alignment of block (3).  We know that in C structs fields are padded to make them start at fixed locations. Block (3) may be unaligned, right? Have you got any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: That's a good question, and one I didn't feel confident enough to answer.  We do know that `malloc()` must return a pointer that can be legally converted to any pointer type (though there's a QoI issue lurking on platforms that allow unaligned access at a performance cost).  You may be able to hint that `Record` needs the strictest possibly alignment, and *I think* that will pad `sizeof (Record)` to be a multiple of the alignment.  Don't take my word for that, though - check on [so] or somewhere.

Comment: It may be instructive to look at the implementation of `malloc()` in your favourite library.  AIUI, most allocators do something similar internally to track allocation sizes, at least for larger allocations.  There might be a lot of special-case code to skim-read, though.